# Autowired property is null - Spring Boot Configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, nullpointerexception, autowired

I am stuck with null values in an autowired property. I am hoping I could get some help.

We are using for the project spring-boot version 0.5.0.M6.

The four configuration files with beans are in one package and are sorted by "area":

1. Data source configuration
2. Global method security configuration (as we use Spring-ACL)
3. MVC configuration
4. Spring Security configuration

The main method that bootstraps everything is in the following file:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
    JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
    SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
    ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class,
    ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
    MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    WebSocketAutoConfiguration.class
})
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class IntegrationsImcApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(
                IntegrationsImcApplication.c lass, args);
    }
}
```

The first file that holds the data source configuration beans is as follows (I have omitted some method body parts to make it more readable):

```
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@Configuration
public class RootDataSourceConfig 
        extends TomcatDataSourceConfiguration 
        implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    @Override
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return jpaDataSource();
    }

    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return jpaTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

    @Bean(name="jpaDataSource")
    public DataSource jpaDataSource() {......}

    @Bean(name = {"transactionManager","txMgr"})
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {......}

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory jpaEmf() {......}
}
```

And here is the next configuration file, that depends on the data source from above. It has about 20 beans related to ACL configuration, but it fails on the firsts bean that uses data source:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class RootGlobalMethodSecurityConfig 
        extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration 
        implements Ordered {

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return IntegrationsImcApplication.ROOT_METHOD_SECURITY_CO NFIG_ORDER;
    }

    @Bean
    public MutableAclService aclService() 
            throws CacheException, IOException {

        MutableJdbcAclService aclService = new MutableJdbcAclService(
                dataSource, aclLookupStrategy(), aclCache());
        aclService.setClassIdentityQuery("SELECT @@IDENTITY");
        aclService.setSidIdentityQuery("SELECT @@IDENTITY");
        return aclService;
    }

    ...................................
}
```

Basically invoking `aclService()` throws an error as `dataSource` is null. We have tried ordering the configuration files by implementing the `Ordered` interface. We also tried using `@AutoConfigureAfter(RootDataSourceConfig.class)` but this did not help either. Instead of doing `@Autowired` on the `DataSource` we also tried injecting the `RootDataSourceConfig` class itself, but it was still null. We tried using `@DependsOn` and `@Ordered` on those beans but again no success. It seems like nothing can be injected into this configuration.

The console output at the startup is listing the beans in the order we want them, with data source being the first. We are pretty much blocked by this.

Is there anything weird or unique we are doing here that is not working? If this is as designed, then how could we inject data source differently?

Repo: [github](https://github.com/doles/spring-boot-autowired-sample)

Comment: There might be some code that we haven't seen that is forcing early instantiation of your `RootGlobalMethodSecurityConfig`.  Could you share the whole project please (e.g. on github)? It's easier to see the whole picture then.

Comment: Some general observations: 1) Most of the `@Order` and `@DependsOn` declarations are probably unnecessary - Spring is smart enough to work out dependencies in most cases. 2) `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` is redundant. 3) All those excludes in the autoconfiguration declaration are also probably redundant and they are definitely distracting. 4) `@AutoConfigureAfter` only applies to autoconfiguration classes, and yours (I assume) are normal component beans.

Comment: Dave, I have pushed the project to github:
[link](https://github.com/doles/spring-boot-autowired-sample).

Comment: @DaveSyer The project starts up with `spring-boot 0.5.0.M5` without any errors. As M5 is using `spring 4.0.0.M3` I tried running `spring-boot 0.5.0.M6 + spring 4.0.0.M3`, and the startup fails.
But it runs ok with `spring-boot 0.5.0.M5 + spring 4.0.0.RELEASE`.

Comment: There is an M7 you can try (and also snapshots). Probably worth a shot (I can look at your project to tomorrow).

Comment: @DaveSyer Github project updated to M7 but same issue as with M6. I created working M5 branch there to compare. Thank you for your interest and Happy New Year!!!

Comment: @DaveSyer I can't comment yet so I posted some new information as an answer. I managed to get it to work. I hope it's the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eager initialization of a bean that depends on a `DataSource` is definitely the problem. The root cause is nothing to do with Spring Boot or autoconfiguration, but rather plain old-fashioned chicken and egg - method security is applied via an aspect which is wrapped around your business beans by a `BeanPostProcessor`. A bean can only be post processed by something that is initialized *very* early. In this case it is too early to have the `DataSource` injected (actually the `@Configuration` class that needs the `DataSource` is instantiated too early to be wrapped properly in the `@Configuration` processing machinery, so it cannot be autowired).  My proposal (which only gets you to the same point with the missing `AuthenticationManager`) is to declare the `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` as a nested class instead of the one that the `DataSource` is needed in:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
protected static class ActualMethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("aclDaoAuthenticationProvider")
    private AuthenticationProvider aclDaoAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("aclAnonymousAuthenticationProvider")
    private AnonymousAuthenticationProvider aclAnonymousAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("aclExpressionHandler")
    private MethodSecurityExpressionHandler aclExpressionHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(aclDaoAuthenticationProvider);
        auth.authenticationProvider(aclAnonymousAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return aclExpressionHandler;
    }
```

}

i.e. stick that inside the `RootMethodSecurityConfiguration` and remove the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation from that class.

Comment: Github repo updated with @DaveSyer solution! Also small tests for `@PreAuthorize` and `@Transactional` added for entity and repository.

Comment: After hours of research I finally came across this answer! Now my issue is result and I can continue with my development. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I might have resolved the problem.

`GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class` has the following setter that tries to autowire permission evaluators:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
public void setPermissionEvaluator(List<PermissionEvaluator> permissionEvaluators) {
    ....
}
```

And in my case the `aclPermissionEvaluator()` bean needs `aclService()` bean, which in turn depends on another autowired property: `dataSource`. Which seems not to be autowired yet.

To fix this I implemented `BeanFactoryAware` and get `dataSource` from `beanFactory` instead:

```
public class RootMethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration implements BeanFactoryAware {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.dataSource = beanFactory.getBean("dataSource", DataSource.class);
    }
    ....
}
```

After this, other exception showed up, where`SecurityAutoConfiguration.class` is complaining about missing AuthenticationManager, so I just excluded it from `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. I am not sure if its ideal, but I have custom security configuration, so this way everything works ok.