# Custom PermissionEvaluation bean is causing circular references and null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to set up Spring Security ACL on Spring 4 but I am getting a null pointer exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.LookupStrategy]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'webSecurityACL' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'lookupStrategy' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource required
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
... 95 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource required
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy.<init>(BasicLookupStrategy.java:145)
at com.sample.application.WebSecurityACL.lookupStrategy(WebSecurityACL.java:59)
```

Here is my java config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityACL extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
EhCacheBasedAclCache aclCache() {
    EhCacheFactoryBean factoryBean = new EhCacheFactoryBean();
    EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheManager = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();

    factoryBean.setCacheName("aclCache");
    factoryBean.setCacheManager(cacheManager.getObject());
    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    return new EhCacheBasedAclCache(factoryBean.getObject(), permissionGrantingStrategy(), aclAuthorizationStrategy());
}

@Bean
AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy() {
    return new AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ACL_ADMIN"));
}

@Bean
PermissionGrantingStrategy permissionGrantingStrategy(){
    return new DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy(new ConsoleAuditLogger());
}

@Bean
LookupStrategy lookupStrategy() {
    return new BasicLookupStrategy(dataSource, aclCache(), aclAuthorizationStrategy(), permissionGrantingStrategy());
}

@Bean
JdbcMutableAclService aclService() {
    JdbcMutableAclService service = new JdbcMutableAclService(dataSource, lookupStrategy(), aclCache());
    //service.setClassIdentityQuery("select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('acl_class', 'id'))");
    //service.setSidIdentityQuery("select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('acl_sid', 'id'))");
    return service;
}

@Bean
PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator(){
    return new AclPermissionEvaluator(aclService());
}

@Bean
AclPermissionCacheOptimizer aclPermissionCacheOptimizer(){
    return new AclPermissionCacheOptimizer(aclService());
}

@Override
protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler(){
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();

    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator());
    expressionHandler.setPermissionCacheOptimizer(aclPermissionCacheOptimizer());

    return expressionHandler;
}
}
```

I pinpointed the culprit to the permissionEvaluator bean. If I replace aclService() with null (just to test):

```
PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator(){
    return new AclPermissionEvaluator(null);
}
```

then I am able to run the application. I can't figure out where the circular reference is. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Here is my gradle file:

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'spring-boot'


buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.7.RELEASE")
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
compile("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3:2.1.2.RELEASE")
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:3.2.8.RELEASE'
compile 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.10.1'
runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is the datasource isnt being injected -

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource required
>   at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
>   at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy.(BasicLookupStrategy.java:145)
>   at com.sample.application.WebSecurityACL.lookupStrategy(WebSecurityACL.java:59)

Can you confirm this? The reason you got rid of the exception is that "AclPermissionEvaluator(null)" is calling the datasource too, and giving an uncaught exception

Comment: If I try "return new AclPermissionEvaluator(null)" then dataSource is not null anymore. If I call aclService(), then dataSource is null. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I think this is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856825/autowired-property-is-null-spring-boot-configuration